# strange behavior when applying custom pandas function to column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to apply a custom function in pandas to a column of strings in a dataframe, but it seems to be taking the entire series as the argument, not the strings themselves.  Things seem to work fine with simpler functions, but not for the one I want to use.  To illustrate my problem, consider the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C': ['blah1, blah2']})
def addb(stra, bla):
    print(str(stra))
    return bla+stra
df[["C"]].apply(addb, bla = 'a')
```

As expected, this adds an "a" in front of everything in the first column, but it turns out that str(stra) is not the string in each cell of the column.  Instead, I get something this printed out:

```
0    blah1, blah2
Name: C, dtype: object
0    blah1, blah2
Name: C, dtype: object
```

I expected and wanted just "blah1" and "blah2" to get printed out, since I thought they were what were being passed into stra. (I need this for functions that require a string as input)  But it seems like the whole series was being passed in.

Comment: Please provide specific example data as input, show the exact effect of your code on the input, and compare it with desired output.  See guidelines for constructing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you are printing out a column and not the string.

Because `DataFrame.apply` is functioning on either a row or a column. So the `stra` you defined in the function `addb` is either a row or a column, a `pd.Series` in both cases.

You can try add `print(type(stra))` in your code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C': ['blah1, blah2']})
def addb(stra, bla):
    print(type(stra))
    # print(str(stra))
    return bla+stra
df = df[["C"]].apply(addb, bla='a')

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

If you want to do it to only the string, the `C` part, you will need to specify it like `stra["C"]` or `stra.C`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C': ['blah1, blah2']})
def addb(stra, bla):
    print(str(stra["C"]))
    return bla+stra["C"]
df[["C"]].apply(addb, axis=1, bla='a')

blah1, blah2

0    ablah1, blah2
dtype: object
```